# How to run test maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem with call unit test from maven task. My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FizzBuzzTDDKata</groupId>
    <artifactId>FizzBuzzTDDKata</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit/junit5-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I add `<scope>` property according some tutorial, but still when I am trying to use `mvn clean install` or 'mvn test' I got:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.950s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 14 16:12:32 CEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using Intellij IDEA 2016.2.5 Ultimate and each maven task is run as run configuration in Intellij. What am I doing wrong? Should I add some other dependencies, builds to `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add

```
<build>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

to your pom.xml as described in [Junit5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven). Than you have to define a TestEngine, which is also descriped in the link.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

...

    ...
    
        org.junit.jupiter
        junit-jupiter-api
        5.0.0-M4
        test

This should be all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also doesn't help me.

Comment: A common issue I know is, that the Test class is not named *Test.java or Test*.java. How did you name it?

Comment: Test class was named `FizzBuzzTest.java`.

Comment: Can I access this project? It would be easier for me to see the issue. Else, I would have to ask you a lot of questions.

Comment: I delete that project and I started to use Junit4, that's probably some issues with my local software.